# display list of data for login user

Tags: python, django

I am testing an app, I want the user to be able to views his own leave but not other users leave when he login, but I cannot seem to come up with the right logic. In my current code only the first name and the last name is displayed on the template, the rest of the data did not seem to display. I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

```
class NewLeave(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default='', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    leave_balances = models.ManyToManyField(Leave_Balance)
    leave = (
        ('annual', 'annual'),

    )

    Leave_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=leave, blank=False, default='annual')
    dp = (
        ('test1', 'test1'),
        ('test2', 'test2'),

    )

    department = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=dp, blank=False, default='')
    Start_Date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
    End_Date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name



def test(request):
    username = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        get_user_fname = request.user.first_name
        get_user_lname = request.user.last_name
        display = User.objects.filter(first_name=get_user_fname, last_name=get_user_lname)
        return render(request, 'test.html', {'display': display})




{%for leave in display%}
      <tr class="success">

        <td>{{leave.first_name}}</td>
        <td>{{leave.last_name}}</td>
        <td>{{leave.user.NewLeave.Leave_type}}</td>
        <td>{{leave.user.NewLeave.department}}</td>
        <td>{{leave.user.NewLeave.Start_Date}}</td>
        <td>{{leave.user.NewLeave.End_Date}}</td>
   </tr>
{%endfor%}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I hope this helps to you:

```
...
...
display = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
...
...
```

Maybe there are more than one user with the same name. And in your template :

```
    <tr class="success">
        <td>{{display.first_name}}</td>
        <td>{{display.last_name}}</td>
        <td>{{display.user.NewLeave.Leave_type}}</td>
        <td>{{display.user.NewLeave.department}}</td>
        <td>{{display.user.NewLeave.Start_Date}}</td>
        <td>{{display.user.NewLeave.End_Date}}</td>
   </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I sort that out by getting the user_id of the login user and then filter the NewLeave by the particular user_id

```html
def test(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        get_user_id = request.user.id
        display = NewLeave.objects.filter(user_id=get_user_id)
        return render(request, 'test.html', {'display': display})
```